# Auto Generated Mail

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Perhaps this kind of question comes under not to ask category but for the sake of application I have to ask.So pardon me.

At the time of Log in,I found that(suppose)If I am unable to remember my password,then I have to put my email-id then an auto generated reply come from that's hosted site with

1. a new link for generating another new password or
2. simply sending password(that means password isn't encrypted,I guess) in reply.

watching the source code it's hard to predict,but I want to know(if they are using jsp) then  which protocol is used for this auto generated mail what are the other things to remember to achive this, while I'm also making an application for auto generated mail.

Comment: [This might give you a better idea.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3303/is-this-a-secure-implementation-of-password-reset-email)

Comment: The SENDING of the mail is largely decoupled from the CONTENTS of the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using javax.mail api in java

google for sending mail using java...

define content of mail in template or resource file and send mail whenever user clicks on forgot password link.

It is using SMTP protocol only.